# prohibit the launching of two emacs

Tags: emacs

When you double click on a file opens a new window emacs. Tell me how to do to open in the same

I beg your pardon, Linux OS

I installed emacs23
Then i run the command:
emacs --daemon &&
emacsclien -c &&
emacsclien -c
And i have opened 2 windows instead of one

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide enough information, such as what OS/windowing system you're using, but the answer involves using emacsclient.  The [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) has all the details of using emacsclient, though not how to set up your OS/windowing system to associate the file types with emacsclient (instead of emacs).

Answer (score 1):

You have a single Emacs instance with two windows. You have two windows because you explicitly asked for them by passing the `-c` option to `emacsclient`.